# KMM dependencies in commonMain

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

If I add coroutines dependency I can use it in shared module.

But if I add my own Kotlin library with `MyClass` class in it, I can't see `MyClass` in shared module:

```
val commonMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation(project(":myKotlinLib"))
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I mark my library module to be "compatible" with KMM shared module?

There is `myKotlinLib`'s gradle config:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'kotlin'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I've created the lib using File -> New -> Module -> Java or Kotlin library (Language: Kotlin)

**UPD**

I've noticed that Build tab has an error:
[image]

Comment: What's the config for `myKotlinLib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to connect a regular Kotlin library but in commonMain of module marked as `kotlin("multiplatform")` in `plugins { ... }` section we can connect only dependencies witch are `kotlin("multiplatform")` too

Answer (score 0):

How did you import the `lib` files?

You might want to import it to a `SharedModule` folder neither `androidApp` nor `iOSApp`